# How to fetch data inside <b> tag while web scraping in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, innerhtml

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://www.marinetraffic.com). i have written the code which opens this website and then searches for a value. clicks on the search result and opens the final page from where i have to pick the details. i need to pick details of  tag mentioned in red  in

[image: this image]

this is my code which opens the desired page. I have used Link.click to open the desired page. After that i need to fetch details mentioned in image. Kindly advise.

```
Sub hullByAshish()
Dim html, html1 As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol, ElementCol1 As Object
Dim Link As Object
Dim appIE As Object
Dim a As String
Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
a = "PONTOVREMON"
With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/search/all/keyword:" & a
    .Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Set html = appIE.document
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
DoEvents
For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link.innerHTML = "PONTOVREMON" Then
Link.Click
End If
Next Link
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")` have you tried modifying this with b.  `innertext` `innerhtml` may help with the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way

```
Dim ie As Object, ieDoc As Object, lnk As Object

Sub hullByAshish()
    Dim IMO As String, MMSI As String, GTon As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    a = "PONTOVREMON"

    With ie
        .Navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/search/all/keyword:" & a
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    Set ieDoc = ie.document

    For Each lnk In ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If lnk.innerhtml = "PONTOVREMON" Then
            lnk.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lnk

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    IMO = GetValue("IMO:")
    MMSI = GetValue("MMSI:")
    GTon = GetValue("Gross Tonnage:")

    Debug.Print "IMO: " & IMO
    Debug.Print "MMSI: " & MMSI
    Debug.Print "Gross Tonnage: " & GTon
End Sub

Function GetValue(s As String) As String
    GetValue = Trim(Split(Split(Split(Trim(Split(ie.document.body.innerhtml, s)(1)))(0), "<b>")(1), "</b>")(0))
End Function

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]